# YouTrack: How to set user's email notification for any activity in any project

Tags: youtrack

How can I set up a saved search on which I can make a user receive notifications for any type of status change on items in any project, or if that's not possible, in any project in which he's simply a member (doesn't need to have reported the item, or have had it assigned to him)?

The 'for:' and 'by:' filters don't seem to give me the capability to set up something like this. Is this possible, to have a sort of 'Super-Watcher' that gets email updates on everything?

I'm self-hosting the free version of YouTrack (4.2.4, build #6055 [24-Jun-2013 20:37]).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a saved search with a query like

> State:Open or State:-Open

This query will match any issue in any project that's visible to the user.

Comment: I'm having trouble figuring out the different between `State:Open` and `State:-Open`. Specifically, the `-` character - it seems yield the results that I would expect without the `-` character, which returns no results for me. It also shows issues in any status, so does `Open` mean *in existence*?

Comment: Ok, I get it now: `-` means to *exclude* issues with the `State` value of `Open`. And you're not giving *two* example queries, but rather *one* query, typed just as you have done ("Give me all project issues that are either open or not open") . Thanks very much!